# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'heroes'"

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I based my work off of the tutorial [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/) as presented on Angular.io.

The app was created with the following command:

```
ng new toh --no-standalone --routing --ssr=false
```

**I understand that "standalone" is the new default, but I opted to do without it since my company is using `15.2.2`.**

However I'm running into an issue that I can't figure out, and it starts in [Chapter 5 (Routing)](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5).

After adding the `app-routing.module.ts` file as instructed, I'm told to add a `router-outlet` to my `app.component.html` file; and that once I've done so I should be able to browse to `/heroes` (the full url: http://localhost:4200/heroes)  and view the list of heroes as constructed in earlier chapters.

However the following error occurs in the console:

```
main.ts:6 ERROR Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'heroes'
    at Recognizer.noMatchError (router.mjs:3654:12)
    at router.mjs:3687:20
    at catchError.js:10:39
    at OperatorSubscriber2._this._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at Subscriber2.error (Subscriber.js:43:18)
    at Subscriber2._error (Subscriber.js:67:30)
    at Subscriber2.error (Subscriber.js:43:18)
    at Subscriber2._error (Subscriber.js:67:30)
    at Subscriber2.error (Subscriber.js:43:18)
    at Subscriber2._error (Subscriber.js:67:30)
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   main.ts:6
Show 26 more frames
```

- I've tried setting the path to `heroes` and to `/heroes`
- I've tried adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to the route definition.
- I've tried explicitly adding the `HeroesComponent` definition to the `imports` array in this file.

FWIW, before I noticed the console error, I tried to move past it and create the DashboardComponent and add the navigation buttons. But this error occurs whether I manually browse to `/heroes` or whether I click a button to take me there.

Here's the complete `src/app/app-routing.module.ts` file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent, },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here's my `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
```

Comment: Tour of heroes was created a few years back and its unclear if they are updating it. I too found it lacking when I did it awhile back. I would advise to learn on Pluralsight or Linked Learning with an instructor which can explain/updates the example code.

Comment: That's definitely something I'd consider. But I also tried the tutorial on angular.io and had similar issues. No shade against Angular, but they've got to realize that this is the front door for people considering the framework. And if it doesn't work that reflects poorly on Angular, not just the people who might have missed some things in the docs.

Comment: I recommend [Angular Essential Training - Derek Perou](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/angular-essential-training-22880732) the example project is on Github codespaces which makes it way easier to run w/o issues. I recommend to create a side angular project based on what was learned there. 


I try not to leverage too many free trainings when it comes to my Vocation. Spending $20, less than a tank of gas, to promote one's career...no brainer. IMHO

Comment: Did you import the `AppRoutingModule` anywhere, as @ΩmegaMan suggested? If so, did you try to stop-and-restart `ng serve` (because `ng-cli` has some quirks) and refresh the Browser (F5, Ctrl-R, or something like that), to be sure your latest code is up-to-date in the browser?

Comment: I checked out the Learning Angular series on YouTube by Mark Thompson, and it was excellent. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1w1q3fL4pmj9k1FrJ3Pe91EPub2_h4jF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not pathing to the heroes component. Check the line

```
 import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
```

Does the pathing make sense. Then look at

```
   { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent, },
```

Do the names match by case? Why is there a comma at the end, but no other items? Remove the comma if no other items.

In `app.module.ts` (*name may be different its at the root level*) is there an import such as

```
 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
```

and is it being imported such as

```
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
```

---

Also provide a default catch-all route to redirect to the start page, this is using the only route you provided:

```
   { path: '**', redirectTo: 'heroes' }
```

Comment: I walked through the tutorial again, starting from the beginning. I copied and pasted code instead of typing it. I'm not sure exactly what I did wrong, but it's working now. Thanks for taking the time to offer suggestions.

Comment: I think the takeaway here is that if you run into problems with a tutorial, try copying and pasting code instead of typing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you follow the tutorial but with standalone components, just do not generate the `AppRoutingModule` and ignore everything said about it.  The routes are now defined in `src/app/app.routes.ts`.

Take a look at the application main entry point `src/main.ts`.  It bootstraps the application with the application configuration imported from `src/app/app.config.ts` which in turn provides the routing with the routes imported from `src/app/app.routes.ts`.  It is actually simpler than before.

Have a look at https://www.guido-flohr.net/standalone-angular-tour-of-heroes/ for a complete list of modifications that are needed to make the tutorial work with standalone components.